# Get cookie from NSURLRequest to WebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, cookies

The goal of my program is to do the following:

Execute a url on my website, which 'logs' the user in using NSURLRequest.  Basically my thought is to execute the request, get the cookie from the response and add the cookie to the WebView.

All I know how to do is execute the first part of this process, and the code is below for that:

```
NSString *fullURL = @"http://mysite.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

content is the name of my webview

```
[content loadRequest:theRequest];
```

Next up is parsing the response.  Basically check for error (the page only outputs the word 'true' or 'false' for error.  I'm guessing I can check for the existence of those words and act appropriately.  And of course, getting a cookie from the response and sending it to 'content'.   Would appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: See here: http://blog.peakji.com/cocoansurlrequest-with-cookies/

Comment: Thanks for the response but im not entirely sure how to use this..particularly where it asks me to input a name and value for the cookie...shouldn't these be set by the cookie returned?

Comment: It sounds like you don't need a UIWebView at all, if you're not displaying HTML inside your app. It sounds like you only need to send a HTTP request and then read the response. You can do that without a web view. Look at the `NSURLConnection` class and 'NSURLResponse' class.

Comment: I am displaying web content inside the app, but it requires a login first, which I want to implement inside of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Normally URL loading system **automatically handles sending and storing** all URL related  **cookies** with your NSURLRequest. However if you want to add an extra cookie, you must use NSMutableURLRequest.

Cookies are part of request response headers, which you can modify like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request addValue:cookie forHTTPHeaderField:"Cookie"];
```

Comment: I still can't get it to work.  Does it matter that the URL for the login is different than the url for the webview? (but they are on the same domain).  There are two separate URLRequests because of this and I think that is throwing it off.

Comment: Do you have UIWebViewDelegate callback webViewDidFinishLoad, where to check returned cookies?